# Proxy Server not able to connect with Backend Server

Tags: apache-httpd, reverse-proxy

I deployed Proxy Server running on Redhat 7.6 and Apache is configured as Reverse Proxy Server. But when i try to open the URL of proxy server in browser in Logs of Reverse proxy server it is giving this error message

```
[Tue Jun 01 08:37:47.399377 2021] [proxy_http:error] [pid 130294] (103)Software caused connection abort: [client 192.168.xx.xxx:43702] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server msolarwinds:443
[Tue Jun 01 08:37:47.399514 2021] [proxy:error] [pid 130294] [client 192.168.xx.xx:43702] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /
```

Solarwinds is running as Backend.

Reverse Proxy VirtualHost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>                                                   
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain                                 
    ServerName revproxy-01.domain                            
    ServerAlias revproxy-01                                      
    Redirect permanent / https://192.168.xxx.xxx                     
  #ProxyPass /Orion/ https://msolarwinds.domain:443/          
  #ProxyPassReverse /Orion/ https://msolarwinds.domain:443/   
    #ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/reverseproxy-error_log"                
    #CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/reverseproxy-access_log" common       
</VirtualHost>                                                       
                                                                     
<VirtualHost *:443>                                                  
SSLEngine on                                                         
SSLProxyEngine on                                                    
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3                                        
SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv2 SSLv3                                    
#SSLProxyProtocol +TLSv1 -TLSv1.2 -SSLv2 -SSLv3                      
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt                         
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key                    
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain                                 
    ServerName revproxy-01.domain                            
    ServerAlias revproxy-01                                      
#<IfModule mod_proxy.c>                                              
#    <Proxy *>                                                       
#        Require all granted                                         
#    </Proxy>                                                        
    # backend server and forwarded path                              
    #SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off                                         
    #SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off                                     
    #SSLProxyCheckPeerName off                                       
    #SSLProxyVerify none                                             
    #ProxyAddHeaders off                                             
                                                                     
    #ProxyRequests off                                               
    #ProxyVia off                                                    
    #ProxyPreserveHost on                                            
    #ProxyPass / https://172.16.xxx.xxx:443/ timeout=7200               
    ProxyPass / https://msolarwinds.domain:443/               
    ProxyPassReverse / https://msolarwinds.domain:443/        
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/reverseproxy-error_log"                 
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/reverseproxy-access_log" common        
#</IfModule>                                                         
</VirtualHost>
```

if i run `curl msolarwinds.domain:443` on RevProxy server it replies with

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>502 Proxy Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Proxy Error</h1>
<p>The proxy server received an invalid
response from an upstream server.<br />
The proxy server could not handle the request <em><a href="/">GET&nbsp;/</a></em>.<p>
Reason: <strong>Error reading from remote server</strong></p></p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: What's the question? What have you tried to fix the issue?

Comment: why do you think im here asking question if issue still persists. Mostly articles are saying change SSLprotocol but it didnt help also

Comment: The thing is, you are not asking questions. You just make a statement. In case you want suggestions for a troubleshooting approach, I would start by checking what status line the backend produces: `curl -k https://msolarwinds:443`.

Comment: We don't know which bit of what is a large problem area you're having an issue with. We don't know what diagnostics you've attempted. We don't even know what your configuration looks like. If this was a professional environment one of my first question would be whether you've asked for help from your IT department

Comment: Agree and thanks, I updated the question and here is the output of curl command "curl: (35) TCP connection reset by peer"

Comment: On this proxy server, what do you get by running `curl https://msolarwinds.domain:443/`? If that generates an error or otherwise fails you need to fix that before progressing any further, because it (partially) emulates the `ProxyPass / https://msolarwinds.domain:443/` instruction

Comment: if i run "curl https://msolarwinds.domain:443/" it replies with "curl: (35) TCP connection reset by peer"

Comment: You now know that the problem is on the backend server.

Comment: yes, i already discussed with Infra team and they said they open the ticket with Solarwinds to help on this issue . i will update the thread with the How-To as soon issue is resolved. So others can benefit if they have same scenario

Comment: Actually the issue was with the certificate, CN was set to Short name and ServerName was set to FQDN, so i recreate the certificate and in CN i gave FQDN , then i was able to access solarwinds. But now im facing entirely new issue "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://msolarwinds.domain.com/api2/swis/query?lang=en-us&swAlertOnError=false&swLogOutOnAuthError=true&viewId=1' from origin 'https://192.168.22.6' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."